# JFrame Component's Size And location

Tags: java, swing, jframe, gridbaglayout

i am  learning  `GridBagLayout` and did very simple layout that is attached,There are two very small confusions
1- `Size of Buttons` i have used    `New.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70,23));`  is it standard way to make all the buttons same size

2-Placing of components  does not look good

[image]

now see  there is much more `padding on all sides of components` , so  how to put it in right way `from top left corner`  , should i decrease size of `JFrame?`  or  use  `frame.pack();` both  work but dont know what is standard practice (i have tried `pagestart` etc)   ,

this is how my code looks

```
    frame= new JFrame("Hello ");
    frame.setSize(300, 150);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.addWindowListener(this);  
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocation(0, 0);
    p1= new JPanel (new GridBagLayout());

    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    lblname= new JLabel("Name");
    gbc.gridx=0; 
    gbc.gridy=0;  

    p1.add(lblname, gbc);

    textname = new JTextField(11);
    gbc.gridx=1; 
    gbc.gridy=0 ; 

    p1.add(textname, gbc);

    New=  new JButton("New"); 
    gbc.gridx=2; 
    gbc.gridy=0;
    New.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70,23));
    p1.add(New, gbc);

    lblEmail = new JLabel("Email "); 
    gbc.gridx=0; 
    gbc.gridy=1;
    p1.add(lblEmail , gbc); 

    TextEmail = new JTextField(11);
    gbc.gridx=1; 
    gbc.gridy=1; 
    p1.add(TextEmail,gbc);

    Edit = new JButton("Edit") ;
    gbc.gridx= 2 ;
    gbc.gridy=1; 
    Edit.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70,23));

    p1.add(Edit , gbc); 

    lblgender= new JLabel("Gender"); 
    gbc.gridx=0; 
    gbc.gridy=2; 
    p1.add(lblgender, gbc); 

    TextGender= new JTextField(11);
    gbc.gridx=1; 
    gbc.gridy=2; 
    p1.add(TextGender, gbc); 

    Gender= new JButton("Gender");
    gbc.gridx=2;
    gbc.gridy=2;
    Gender.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70,23));

    p1.add(Gender, gbc);

    pre= new JButton("<<");
    gbc.gridx=0; 
    gbc.gridy=3; 
    p1.add(pre, gbc);

    count =  new JTextField(5);
    gbc.gridx=1; 
    gbc.gridy=3; 
    p1.add(count, gbc);

    next= new JButton(">>");
    gbc.gridx=2; 
    gbc.gridy=3; 
    next.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70,23));

    p1.add(next, gbc);


    p1.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(p1);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: For best quick replies, consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Like your new slogan, over Andrew Thompson's ;)

Comment: Yes, `pack()` is the standard practice.

Comment: GridBagLayout has a anchor property, which will determine how a component is aligned within its cell. You should avoid setPreferredSize where possible, instead, use something like fill = HORIZONTAL instead

Comment: I recommend that you not set any sizes at all, that you let the layouts do this for you.

Comment: @MadProgrammer this one gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GridBagLayout` will drive you nuts, it's also one of the most flexible layout managers available in the JDK.

Don't be afraid to use compound layouts.  In the example below, I've moved the navigation controls to there own panel, which makes it much easier to define complex layouts (you can also mix layout managers this way)

`GridBagConstraints#fill` allows you to determine how components may be filled within there cell.  You have `GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL`, `GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL` and `GridBagConstraints.BOTH` ... I think there meaning is self explanatory.

In the example below, I've used `GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL` to allow the buttons to fill all the available space within their cell/column

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class TestLayout20 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestLayout20();
    }

    public TestLayout20() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            JLabel lblname = new JLabel("Name");
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;

            add(lblname, gbc);

            JTextField textname = new JTextField(11);
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 0;

            add(textname, gbc);

            JLabel lblEmail = new JLabel("Email ");
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            add(lblEmail, gbc);

            JTextField TextEmail = new JTextField(11);
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            add(TextEmail, gbc);

            JLabel lblgender = new JLabel("Gender");
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 2;
            add(lblgender, gbc);

            JTextField TextGender = new JTextField(11);
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 2;
            add(TextGender, gbc);

            JButton New = new JButton("New");
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 12, 0, 0);
            gbc.gridx = 2;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            add(New, gbc);

            JButton edit = new JButton("Edit");
            gbc.gridx = 2;
            gbc.gridy = 1;

            add(edit, gbc);

            JButton Gender = new JButton("Gender");
            gbc.gridx = 2;
            gbc.gridy = 2;

            add(Gender, gbc);

            JPanel pnlNav = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            gbc.insets = new Insets(12, 0, 0, 0);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 3;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

            add(pnlNav, gbc);

            JTextField count = new JTextField(5);
            gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            pnlNav.add(count, gbc);

            JButton pre = new JButton("<<");
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            pnlNav.add(pre, gbc);

            JButton next = new JButton(">>");
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            gbc.gridx = 2;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            pnlNav.add(next, gbc);

        }
    }
}
```

I highly recommend that you have a read through [How to use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for a better explanation :P

Comment: sure  i will have to read it :)very helpful . thanks a lot  dear